# Как запустить программу C++, которая была скомпилирована в другой Linux ОС

Tags: c++, linux, unix, кроссплатформенность

Есть программа написанная на С++, скомпилированная в другой Linux ОС.

**(Ubuntu BusinessPack 18.04 UALinux Release: 18.04)**:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "TEST BUILDS" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Компиляцию делал так:

Среда разработки: **Code Blocks 16.01** , компилятор: **GNU GCC Compiler** - **без флагов**.

[Настройки компиляции в Code Blocks](https://clip2net.com/s/48zLT1M)

После компиляции, исполняемый файл был перенесен на другую Linux ОС.

**(CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) Kernel Version): 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64)**

При запуске ничего не выводит, ошибок нету. Выставление прав на бинарник не помогло.

Как скомпилировать, чтобы при переносе исполняемого файла на другую Linux ОС программа работала.

Желательно без использования сторонних библиотек и без работы с API ОС.

Comment: Придется переносить его вместе с тем linux, для которого он собран, в виде образа виртуальной машины. Если модули ядра аналогичные, то можно ограничится докер образом.

Comment: "ошибок нету" - не может быть: что выводит `echo $?` после попытки запуска?

Comment: ошибок нету" - не может быть: что выводит echo $? после попытки запуска? - 0 выводит

Comment: А что будет если собрать с `-static`?

Comment: надо будет попробовать  appimage.org , было бы интересно узнать как пакует, не добавляет ли какой то триалки или "пасхалок"

Comment: Лучше всё-таки принять линуксовую парадигму, чем городить велосипеды. Или компилируйте по месту, или разверните для компиляции такую же систему (проще всего в виртуалке, наверное). Исходите из того, что линуксы бинарно несовместимы, но в основном совместимы на уровне исходников. Так сэкономите себе массу времени и нервов.

Comment: @user7860670 - "Придется переносить его вместе с тем linux, для которого он собран, в виде образа виртуальной машины.' - обалдеть !!! Это ещё зачем ?!!! Если линукс для одной архитектуры (например - х86), одной разрядности (например - 32) и все необходимые библиотеки в новой системе уже есть, то заработает абсолютно без всяких проблем.

Comment: @PHPWork - "При запуске ничего не выводит, ошибок нету." Чудес не бывает. Либо Ваша программа **не** запустилась и тогда **должны** быть сообщения об ошибках. Либо она запустилась, отработала, а Вы просто не видите строку  "TEST BUILDS" . Расскажите **подробно** как Вы запускали программу и что при этом происходило.

Comment: кроме статической сборки, есть ещё один вариант - собирать на том линуксе, где "минимальные версии библиотек". Либо задать их ручками (это может быть сложнее, особенно с glib).

Comment: Походу универсального решения для данной проблемы нету. Для разных версий Linux необходимо компилировать под них. Хотелось бы иметь какую то IDE которая дает возможность выбрать ОС под которую необходимо скомпилировать программу. Может кто подскажет IDE ?

Comment: *"универсального решения для данной проблемы нету"* Нет *единого* решения. Посмотрите в сторону flakpak, appimage, snap, и всего такого.

Comment: "универсального решения для данной проблемы нету" Нет единого решения. Посмотрите в сторону flakpak, appimage, snap, и всего такого - к сожалению не могу использовать, не уверен что на  linux хостингах вообще поддерживаются.

Comment: Нашел Holy Build Box для теста использую пример из их документации github.com/phusion/holy-build-box/blob/master/…. Компиляцию выполняю на виртуальной машине Ubuntu + Docker. После компиляции запуск на вирт. Ubuntu проходит нормально, все работает. При переносе на другой Linux хост (CentOS) при запуске бинарника получаю ошибку : segmentation fault . Что нужно сделать что бы этот бинарник нормально работал?

Answer (score 1):

Для сборки переносимого приложения лучше всего использовать `-static`. Приложение будет включать все зависимости внутри одного файла.

Динамическая сборка будет работать на более новых линуксах, на которых версия glibc выше или совпадает. Остальные зависимости можно положить рядом с исполняемым файлом. Проверить зависимости можно через программу `ldd`.

Для питона есть проект [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) - это набор докер образов с допиленной glibc, Собранный в контейнере код запустится почти везде. Тут несложно войти в контейнер и запустить сборку-ликовку сишного кода в нем

Comment: *"Остальные зависимости можно положить рядом с исполняемым файлом"* Не все так просто. Нужно собирать с флажком `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'`. Плюс, если библиотеки используют друг друга, то для них нужно тоже как-то поменять rpath, например с помощью `patchelf`.

Comment: или добавить `LD_PATH`

Comment: Ни -static, ни докер, в общем случае не делают приложение переносимым.

Comment: приложение не переносится в докере. мэнилинукс собирает glibc с совместимой с большинством линуксов

Answer (score 1):

При переносе на другой Linux, важно чтобы там версия библиотеки glibc была равной или больше.

А у вас компиляция идёт на glibc 2.27 (ubuntu 18.04), а на CentOS 7 она 2.17, поэтому код с большой вероятностью не заработает.

Обычно для наибольшей переносимости стараются релиз компилировать на самом старом Linux с минимальной glibc, а дальше он обычно без проблем запускается на более свежих версиях дистрибутивов.

P.S.
Хотя ради интереса я попробовал ваш код запустить на CentOS-7 после компиляции на Ubuntu 18.04, и он отработал! Не знаю, почему лично у вас не получилось.