# Holy Build Box и Docker кросс компиляция под Linux

Tags: linux, docker, build

Для теста использую пример из их документации https://github.com/phusion/holy-build-box/blob/master/TUTORIAL-1-BASICS.md. 
Компиляцию выполняю на виртуальной машине Ubuntu + Docker. 
После компиляции запуск на вирт. Ubuntu проходит нормально, все работает. 
При переносе на другой Linux хост (CentOS) при запуске бинарника получаю ошибку : segmentation fault .
Что нужно сделать что бы этот бинарник нормально работал?

Comment: Это случаем не дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1158765/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-linux-%d0%9e%d0%a1 ?

Comment: Не дубликат но продолжение вопроса, к сожалению его так и не решил.